# bash variable doubles in value - why?

Tags: bash, shell, loops, variables, raspberry-pi

I have a simple shell script set up to capture images every X seconds. For some reason the value of X seems to double each time through the loop.

```
#!/bin/bash

# basic setup for time-lapse

SECONDS=1

while true
do
    DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M%S")
    filename=${DATE}_img.jpg
#   fswebcam -r 1280x720  --timestamp "%a %Y-%b-%d %H:%M (%Z)"  /home/pi/JPGS/$filename
    date
    echo "pausing for ${SECONDS} seconds"
    sleep $SECONDS
    date
    echo "====="
done
```

This is the output I get. The value of SECONDS is not manipulated inside the loop, so I'm confused with what is happening here. Also, the original interval was 30 seconds, I changed it to 1 seconds for testing purposes, and the date calls are for testing/debugging too.

```
Sun Mar  3 17:51:57 CST 2019
pausing for 1 seconds
Sun Mar  3 17:51:58 CST 2019
=====
Sun Mar  3 17:51:58 CST 2019
pausing for 2 seconds
Sun Mar  3 17:52:00 CST 2019
=====
Sun Mar  3 17:52:00 CST 2019
pausing for 4 seconds
Sun Mar  3 17:52:04 CST 2019
=====
Sun Mar  3 17:52:04 CST 2019
pausing for 8 seconds
Sun Mar  3 17:52:12 CST 2019
=====
Sun Mar  3 17:52:12 CST 2019
pausing for 16 seconds
Sun Mar  3 17:52:28 CST 2019
=====
Sun Mar  3 17:52:28 CST 2019
pausing for 32 seconds
Sun Mar  3 17:53:00 CST 2019
=====
Sun Mar  3 17:53:00 CST 2019
pausing for 64 seconds
Sun Mar  3 17:54:04 CST 2019
=====
Sun Mar  3 17:54:04 CST 2019
pausing for 128 seconds
```

What am I missing here?

This is under a Raspberry Pi

Comment: Any time something funky happens when you are using an `ALLCAPS` variable, check `man bash` or `info bash` to make sure you are not using a special variable name (which is also why using variable names in `ALLCAPS` is discouraged....)

Comment: I'll remember to check next time .. been scripting for a while, never come across this particular env variable before. Thanks for the tip on checking @DavidC.Rankin

Comment: Almost 20 years and I only vaguely recalled `SECONDS` buried in the man page. Had to look to be sure `:)`

Comment: @Levon the common shell programming convention is to only use all upper case names for exported variables to avoid exactly this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks @EdMorton .. I'll have to read up on this some more. For most of my time I've used the t/csh, I've only recently converted to bash. I never was quite clear on the export command in bash for setting variables, this will make me find out more.

Comment: You're welcome. That's not specific to any one flavor of shell - it's been the issue and convention since the very first `sh`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pick a different name for `$SECONDS`.

`$SECONDS` is a built-in shell variable. It expands to the number of seconds since the shell was started.

From the [Bash manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html):

> 'SECONDS'
>
> This variable expands to the number of seconds since the shell was 
>   started.  Assignment to this variable resets the count to the value 
>   assigned, and the expanded value becomes the value assigned plus  the
>   number of seconds since the assignment.

Comment: You be faster in man bash than I today `:)`. `man bash` then `/SECONDS` - gah! Keith won...

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin: Actually I used `info bash`.

Comment: That explains the slightly different verbiage, e.g. `"If a value is assigned to SECONDS, the value returned upon subsequent references is the number of seconds since the assignment plus the value assigned."`

Answer (score 2):

`$SECONDS` is actually a special [Bash Variable](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Variables.html#Bash-Variables) for timing the number of seconds a script has been running. Because it's a timer, it increments automatically every second without the script doing anything. Just change the variable name to something else and you should be fine.

Comment: Please don't link to the "Advanced" Bash Scripting guide. It's full of bad practices and poor descriptions. There's nothing "internal" about any of those variables; they are all explicitly exposed to the user. It doesn't even get the entry on `SECONDS` entirely right, leaving out the fact that you can assign to it to reset the starting point.

Comment: @chepner Thank you very much! Edited; now links to the GNU Bash manual (just like the other answer on the page).